# get current status instead timerange

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

in Azure workbooks with the below query I am able to get avg of 2 columns a as per time range selected but here least time we can select is 30 mins we have a requirement to show last 1 min status of the result for that I need another column and show last 1 mins status

```
let start = {TimeRange:start};
let grain =  {TimeRange:grain};
workspace(name).site1_CL 
| extend healty=iff(Status_s == 'Connected' , 100 , 0)
| summarize table1= avg(healty) by ClientName_s
|join
(workspace(name).site2_CL
| extend Availability=iff(StatusDescription_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
|summarize table2=avg(Availability) by  ClientName_s
 )
 on ClientName_s
| extend HealthStatus=(table1+table2)/2 
| project Client=ClientName_s,Environment=EnvName_s,HealthStatus
```

req another column and show current status instead aggregation of selected timerange this column should override selected timerange and show last 1 minute aggregation of 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

Couldn´t you just set the start to use the value you need?

```
let start = now(-1m); //last minute
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Silva..in azure workbooks we can have drill down dashboard so we can set timerange as a parameter so, let start = {TimeRange:start}; will take that parameter that will show aggregation status of 2 tables for the selected time range but my requirement is we need another column which gives aggregation of  last one minute status always this need to be override selected timerange parameter